# Word extraction multiline text file

Tags: python-2.7

> Here I have created a code to: Extract indivisual words from a text file, Append only the words with no duplicates into a blank list and Sort them by alphabetical order.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fhandle = open(fname)
wordlist = list()
counter = 0

for line in fhandle:
line = line.split()
length = len(line)
if line not in wordlist:
    wordlist.append(line[counter])
    counter += 1
    if counter == length:
        break
print wordlist.sort()
```

> Checking this in Pycharm still gives result 'None' although looking at live execution shows the words sorted in alphabetically ordered list but with duplicated words intact (see figures). I would love to decipher difference between append from file [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWnv9.jpg) and from a variable [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgcUw.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Segmenting lines at first with one for-loop and segmenting line into words with another for-loop was the solution I finally came up with :D

```
askfile = raw_input('Enter file name :')
filehandle = open(askfile)
wordlist = list()

for line in filehandle:
    line = line.split()
    for word in line:
        if word not in wordlist:
            wordlist.append(word)
            continue
wordlist.sort()
print wordlist
```

> Now this is a short simple code :D

Answer (score 0):

> The sort() and reverse() methods modify the list in place for economy of space when sorting or reversing a large list. To remind you that they operate by side effect, they don’t return the sorted or reversed list.

what you want is:

```
wordlist.sort()
print wordlist
```